# Get sentence vector for a K-means clustering task

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, vectorization, gensim, word2vec

I am working on a project which groups jobs posted on various job portals into clusters based on the description of the jobs using K-means.

I found the work vector using Word2Vec, but i guess this will not serve the purpose as I will need a vector of the whole job description.

I know that I can average out the word vector of a sentence to get the sentence vector but worried about the accuracy as this will loose the ordering of the words.

Is there any other way I can get the vectors ?

Answer (score 1):

The most using approaches for text vectorization:

1. Pure [TF-IDF](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html), still can be useful, especially using n-grams.
2. Using Word2Vec to get vectors for the words. For the whole text using the mean value of all vectors.
3. Combine the first two methods: get a weighted mean of all words in the text using the coefficients from the TF-IDF.

I would suggest trying each and pick what is performed better in your case. The results can be slightly different depends on the nature of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can facilitate transfer learning by very useful sentence embedding methods such as [Bert-as-service](https://bert-as-service.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [SentenceBert](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers)  or even [Universal Sentence encoding](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4). All of them are easy to use and full of tutorials on the web. They will work better then TF-IDF in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try doc2vec, an extension of word2vec that builds representations of a whole document. There is an implementation in gensim available:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html